# Image inside folder with two-letter name ('bg') disappears when packaged as UWP app

Tags: windows, uwp, uwp-xaml

I've got a really weird problem building a Windows 10 UWP app. When I test on my device in both debug and release modes, an image I set as Background appears perfectly fine. It resizes, etc.

However, when I package the app in preparation for store deployment and install the package to test, images are showing as white.

Here's the code in question:

```
  mainGrid.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/bg/" + Config.bgImage + ".jpg")), Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill };
```

What confuses me the most is why it works in debug/release, but only fails when its released as a package.

The image is set as "Content" and "Copy Always".

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you check if the image is actually in the package? (Build Store packages from your project, then you can rename the `.appx` to `.zip` and look inside.

Comment: Ahh I see what's happened. I had a folder called "bg", for some reason the folder doesn't show when packaged. I figured out the reason is because of the setting to bundle the app - which expects folders / files to be named in a certain way.  

Once I set the appxbundle to be "never", all folders get included, and the background appears.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comment, this is due to a folder being named `bg` and the project being set to create a "bundle" (ie, a main package and then a separate package for each language).

For better or worse, the packaging system assumes that any directory with a 2-letter name is a language code (like "en" or "de") and therefore assumes the assets are specific to that language. Those assets are placed in a separate package that are only installed if applicable for the current user.

If you have a large number of assets, and you're localizing them, using a bundle is still a good approach to minimize the app size and download time, in which case you would need to change the directory name to something a bit longer (technically you can control the packaging yourself but it's a lot of work... renaming is probably easier).

But if you don't localize / aren't worried about bloating the app too much, then creating a single package is fine.

Comment: Ahh this makes sense! Though not immediately obvious, bg is the country and language code for Bulgaria(n), which is probably why things got complicated. Thanks!

Comment: ... And for future-proofing, any two letters are assumed to be a language.